# Change the fields and field names in Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have an old project at work built in Visual Studio 2015 which I'm updating. There are eight text fields in the setup project. They all have names like `FOOBAR` and `QWERTY` which are available in `ProjectInstaller.cs`. If I change the default value for `FOOBAR` such as `bazqux` (hard coded default) or `[FOOBAR]` (passing from the arguments), that gets reflected in `ProjectInstaller.cs`.

However, if I add a new field, that doesn't get reflected in `ProjectInstaller.cs`. Also, renaming a field is not reflected.

This is how the setup project is set up:

[image]

How do I register a new field name or a name change to a field so I can use the new name in `ProjectInstaller.cs`?

Answer (score 1):

I found an article here that gave me the clues to find the settings in VS2015: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/12780/a-setup-and-deployment-project-that-passes-paramet

1. In **Solution Explorer**, select the `<My_Project>_Setup` project
2. In the top right corner of **Solution Explorer**, press the icon for "**Custom Actions Editor**"

   [image: Custom Actions Editor]
3. In **Custom Actions (<My_Project>_Setup)** immediately below "**Commit**", select "**Primary output from <My_Project> (Active)**"

   [image]
4. In **Properties**, edit the value for "**CustomDataAction**", matching the field names to the command arguments. The format is `/ARGUMENT="[FIELDNAME]"`, so the arguments and fields do not have to have the same names. Each pair of argument and field names are separated from the next pair with a single space.

   [image]

Some gotchas:

- The field values are not escaped before being inserted, so a trailing backslash `\` in a field value will most likely cause the installer to fail due to not being able to parse the arguments correctly.
- Argument insertion is made possible by knowing the format of the arguments. E.g. inputting `foobar" /QWERTY="This is bad!` (no starting or trailing double quote) in a field during the installation process will insert a new argument called `QWERTY` with the value `This is bad!`.
- Arguments to the installer can also be injected in this manner.
- Arguments to the .msi file are passed through the installer fields (and possibly edited by the user) before being passed to the installer. E.g. `My_Project_Setup.msi FOO=42` [Edit1Property: `BAR`, Edit1Value: `[FOO]`], [CustomDataAction: `/BAZ="[BAR]"`] will pass `42` (assuming the user didn't change it) in the argument `BAZ` which would then be used in `Context.Parameters["BAZ"]` in `ProjectInstaller.cs`.